# merging the dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table, rdbms

I am trying to merge the five related `data.frames` in `R` by using `merge()` from the package `data.table`.

When I merge the `data.frames`, the data becomes huge with multiple repeat ids (the rows are still distinct).

But if I want to report the outcome for only the unique ids.

- Should I delete the rows with repeated ids? But that will delete the data.
- How to deal such thing?

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: The data I am working on is huge but here is the summary : my dta.frame1 (customers_info) has 128595 obs and 11 variables while the data.frame2 (transaction_info) has 1324566 obs and 7 variables. I am merging data.frame2 to data.frame1 with the id "customer_id". But it becomes so huge that it doesn't even allocate the memory.

Comment: It seems the key has duplicate values. how to avoid them?

Comment: first summarise on key values, or perform an update-join, or... or...
impossible to answer without sample data. please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Hello, would love to help but you'll need to be a bit more specific first. Try this page for some advise about how to distill your Q into something more easily communicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example